# Bind to an ItemsControl's Templated Parent from inside the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

What is the proper way to bind to the Parent of an ItemsControl from within the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate?

Non working attempt:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ParentUserControl}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionViewSource.View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  Focusable="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ChildUserControl BoundProp1="{Binding Prop1}"
                     BoundObjProp2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource    
                     Mode=FindAncestor, 
                     AncestorType={x:Type local:ParentUserControl}}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
        </ItemsControl>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution to this problem. In the end I had to use work arounds which violated my desired separation of concerns, but functioned as expected. I believe this comes down to an issue in the wpf framework, hopefully 4.5 will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The binding looks fine to me, but you do not specify a `Binding.Path`, are you sure that you want to bind directly to the control and not a property?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In this case, that is exactly what i am wanting to do. My childcontrol needs to access the instance of the parent... I am getting a binding error however.

Comment: Sorry, sent that reply via cellphone. The actual 'error' (which comes across only as an info message strangely) is:
`System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ChildUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'BoundObjProp2' (type 'ParentUserControlsInheritedClass')`

Comment: @ach: Those might only be temporary, that's why it's not a warning or an error, is the value null when you need it? If so that would be a problem of course...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement and the following worked for me:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="{Binding ItemWidth}" ItemHeight="{Binding ItemHeight}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <views:MyUserControl
                Width="{Binding DataContext.ItemWidth, ElementName=PageRoot}"
                Height="{Binding DataContext.ItemHeight, ElementName=PageRoot}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

P.S. my app is in XAML for WinRT

Comment: Thanks for submitting a response. I think it's always good to add information to a question where the answer was not final, no matter the timing.